# prevent `set` event to fire when calling `val()` in noUiSlider

Tags: javascript, nouislider

I have a noUiSlider set up and I set the value of the handles using the `val()` function. After doing that the `set` event is thrown. This is according to spec, but I don't want that. However, the spec also says this:

> Set
>
> Whenever a slider is changed to a new value, this event is fired.
>   This function will trigger every time a slider stops changing,
>   optionally even on calls to the .val() method. Because this creates
>   the hazard of an infinite loop, any .val() call will have to
>   explicitly request this event. You can consider this 'end of slide'.

[src](http://refreshless.com/nouislider/events-callbacks/)

So I guess it is possible to not fire the `set` method, but I can't find how to do this. Any ideas?

Edit: I just dove into the source code and saw this in the `valueSet` function:

```
    // Fire the 'set' event. As of noUiSlider 7,
    // this is no longer optional.
    fireEvents(['set']);
```

So I guess, it is no longer optional.

Comment: I would like to know this too, is there some workaround?

Comment: nope, it not longer is optional. You could change the source code of course. :/